# Room Flow not triggered on delete when using @RawQuery

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, androidx

I am listening for changes in my local database with

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM favorite_recipes_table ORDER BY id ASC")
fun readFavoriteRecipesAsFlow(): Flow<List<FavoriteEntity>>
```

But when I run another method in my DAO to delete items in the same table:

```kotlin
@RawQuery
suspend fun deleteFavoritesRecipe(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): Int
```

The flow returned from `readFavoriteRecipesAsFlow` is not called. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `@RawQuery` was used.

According to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235373409

> The delete function in the sample project actually uses a @RawQuery method which does not have info on the type of operation being done, hence does not know it's a WRITE. This results in a transaction not being run which means invalidation is never kicked off

A workaround is to add `@Transaction` in the query method:

```kotlin
@RawQuery
@Transaction
suspend fun deleteFavoritesRecipe(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): Int
```

Or you can rethink how you need to make this query to use simple annotations such as `@Query`, `@Delete`, etc.

An issue was opened requesting this feature to notify for changes when using `@RawQuery` at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235878346, but no updates were made from the past 2 years.